# Decomposition of a time series based on another time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, decomposition

I have a general question about decomposition of time series. I have a time series for electricity consumption of one building in hourly resolution for 1 year. This building also has an air conditioner. As you can imagine the electricity consumption of the air conditioner strongly depends on the outside temperature while other electrical appliances in the household (like TV or washing machine) might not depend (or just to a lesser degree) on the temperature.

Now my question is whether it is generally possible to decompose the time series of the electricity consumption into a time series that is dependant on the outside temperature (of course the 'external' time series of the outside temperature is given) and into another time series that in independant from the outside temperature? So at the end I would like to have 2 time series instead of 1. One of those should have a high correlation with the outside temperature whereas the other should not.

Do you have any idea if this is possible and what kind of methods are suitable for such a task.

**Reminder**: Does anyone have an idea.
I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Comment: You could start by a regression model of consumption series on temperature (and other relevant vars like time of day). Then find the temperature where consumption is lowest, predict the series *for that temperature* and use that as a *normal consumption series*. Decompose by subtracting that predicted series from the observed? somethink like that ...

Comment: Thanks kjetil for your answer.  I have several questions to your suggested approach 1)What do you mean by "and other relevant vars like time of day"? There are not other variables that I observe other than temeprature, timestamps and electrical load. 2) What do you mean by "Then find the temperature where consumption is lowest"? Shall I look for just one time stamp with the lowest temperature? How can I then predict the series for that temperature as you suggested? 3) What is a "normal consumption series"?

Comment: 1) I guess consumption might depend also on time of day, and maybe (depending on type of building) if it is workday or not. So this variables must be in model. 2) For the fitted model from 1), find the temperature that predicts lowest consumption. Maybe that will depend on the other vars ... if so you must think about what to do. 3) With that frase I just meant the series corrected for overuse due to temperature. Then: This is only meant as a starting point, but I would like to hear if something like it can work.

Comment: Thanks kjetil for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. To be totally honest, I do not really understand why I should find the temperature with the lowest consumption and what I should do with that? What use is it to have that? Basically I would like to decompose the time series as described in my question. Why do I need the lowest temperature from a regression model. Further, as you pointed out, the lowest consumption will most probably not only depend on the temperature but also on the weekdays and time of day. So I am quite confused as to how to impelment your suggested approach

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks kjetil for your answer. Any comments to my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: I am trying to write one, just wait some ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Hi, you said 5 days ago that you were trying to write a comment on my last comments. Are you still in the process of doing it?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Any comments to my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: As I do not really understand your approach would you mind explaining it once again (see my last comments)?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Would you mind commenting on my last comments? You said that your were trying to write a response. Are you still intending to do this?

Comment: Hi. Well, one model can be ar "family". other, temp to electricty can be like lm y~x (y electricity depends on x temp).

Comment: Thanks user2120 for your answer. I have to admit that I do not really understand what you mean. What do you mean by "family" and how can I create the model?

Comment: @user2120: Any comment to my last comment? I'd highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: hi @PeterBe . sorry didnt get notification until now ^^ .. you can do lm in r, where x could be some ar components of y, and x also contain weather and fit it together (simple but maybe not best) ... im not sure if you want to build your starter model(s) or you profesional and im unable to understand ^^

Comment: Thanks user2120. No, I am not a professional and I have to admit that I do not understand your suggested approach. Basically I want to decompose a time series based on another time series (weather data) such that the original time series is divided into 2 time series. One of those has no correlation with the weather data and the other has high correlation with the weather data. But maybe something like this is just not possible?

Comment: @PeterBe you can model (electricity~weather) .. then take residuals (errors). now, 1. timeseries have 100% correlation ele~weather .. and 2. timeseries are just residuals - but you can model them to improve/enhance precision

Comment: Thanks user2120 for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. What do you mean by "but you can model them to improve/enhance precision"? How can I do that?

Comment: @PeterBe maybe chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127436/test1234 ?